# Any suggestions on how to wait for an unknown length packet on a socket, and do some processing with its payload bytes as efficiently as possible?

Tags: java, sockets, udp, byte, datagram

I need to write an UDP server which will wait for packets from uncorrelated devices (max 10000 of them) sending small packets periodically; do some processing with the payload and write the results on SQL. Now I'm done with the SQL part through jdbc, but the payload bytes keep bugging me, how should I access them? Until now I've worked with the payload mapped to a string and then converting the string to hex (two hex chars representing one byte). I'm aware that there's a better way to do this but I don't know it...

Comment: Why not store the bytes as bytes? e.g. with a BLOB

Comment: why do don't save the byte[] from the DatagramPacket's as blobs on your database

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do you not just want to create a `DatagramSocket` and receive `DatagramPacket`s on it?

You need to specify a *maximum* length of packet by virtue of the buffer you use to create it, but then you'll be able to find out how much data was *actually* sent in the packet using `getLength()`.

See the [Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/datagrams/clientServer.html) for more details and an example.

Comment: I do have a byte array of length 1400, and I use it for the `DatagramPacket` but when i print the packet contents it displays a padded packet (zeros after the received data)

Comment: @V4R15: Sounds like you're ignoring `getLength()`, which should tell you how much of the data you should actually be interested in.